# ionic - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.ionic.starter/io.ionic.starter.MainActivity}

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en ionic, cuando trato de construir el apk y lo corro en android studio, obtengo este error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.ionic.starter/io.ionic.starter.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview. 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview. 
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:82)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebViewEngine(CordovaActivity.java:206)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView(CordovaActivity.java:202)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:80)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:146) 
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:224) 
        at io.ionic.starter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.CookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies
        at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemCookieManager.<init>(SystemCookieManager.java:39)
        at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine.<init>(SystemWebViewEngine.java:86)
        at com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine.<init>(IonicWebViewEngine.java:44)
```

Ya revise el archivo llamado, proguard-custom.txt, y ya tiene algunos permisos

These clases contain references to cordova webView
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.** {*; }
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.*

Estos son las versiones que estoy utilizando.
Cordova Version
6.11.10
Node VERSION
v12.18.4
api level android 15
Android 4.0.3

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Thank you. i did not know